# how to keep info on my main form when closing the secondary form

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to have the user select a code from a combo box that I need it to pass to my frmmenu.

> Option Explicit On Imports System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection Imports
> System.Data.OleDb Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
>
> Public Class FrmMenu
> Friend PinLC As String,
> SwedgeLC As String,
> MonoLC As String,
> StrandLC As String,
> WireLC As String,
> TipLC As String,
> LenLC As String,
> TailLC As String,
> PackLC As String,
> LabelLC As String

then I have radio buttons that open different forms which each save info to each one of those strings above. We click on the form that will give me the SwedgeLC

> Public Class FrmExtras
> Dim MREDLC As String,
> WREDLC As String,
> Swage As String
>
> ```
>     Private Sub CboOptions2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CboOptions2.SelectedIndexChanged
> Swage = UCase(CboOptions2.Text)
> If Swage.Substring(0, 5) = "SWAGE" Then
>       FrmMenu.SwedgeLC = "A"
> End If
> frmmenu.show()
> me.close()
> ```

but on my frmmenu It doesnt keep the code "A" in this case, I never close the frmmenu I only just hide it. But when I go to show my codes on form1(frmmenu) its null. This I think  happens becuase of when I go to open form 3, Form 2 will also open and that resets my code back to null. if I open form 4, form 3 and 2 open and resets both those codes to null. If I close the main form1, then the info isn't saved at all it only remembers the last form I picked the code for not all the others.

Comment: I think there is a whole lot of other things going on here that we can't see.  Could you update your question and explain FrmMenu.SwedgeLC is, how it is set etc.  How are you making your frmOptions visible, does frmOptions have a reference of any sort to the ACTUAL instance of frmMenu or is frmMenu the default instance (ie. classname)?

Comment: Instead of using the old vb `Strings.UCase()` try the .net `CboOptions2.Text.ToUpper`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I figured out the problem, why other forms would open it was set to change and not click for the private sub. Now my data is coming over.

Answer (score 1):

```
    `Private Sub CboOptions2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CboOptions2.SelectedIndexChanged
Swage = UCase(CboOptions2.Text)
If Swage.Substring(0, 5) = "SWAGE" Then
      FrmMenu.SwedgeLC = "A"
End If
frmmenu.show()`
```

without the `me.Close` just try to comment that out.
Then in form2 just add `Me.Close` in the close button

Comment: I tried this but doesnt work leaves the form up but if I click to open form 3, it opens but so does form 2, and any previous form I opened. For exmapl form 1 is there I then select to open form 2, Pick my options then I click done, it goes back to form 1. Then I go to form 3, it will open but form 2 will also open but for no reason.

Comment: What would not closing the form have to do with it? Did you try this or just guess.

Comment: Yes i tried it. Not closing the form and I open another form has different forms open up. If I close form 1 then it loses the variable I am trying to pass through.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are using default instances. In the frmMenu (I am calling it Form1) You should have a Friend field called SwedgeLC. It is Friend so it can be visible to all the classes in your project.

```
Public Class Form1

    Friend SwedgeLC As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.Show()
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        MessageBox.Show(SwedgeLC)
    End Sub

End Class

Private Class Form2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form1.SwedgeLC = "A"
        Form1.Show()
        Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Yes I am using the default instances but I did have public SwedgeLC as string and not friend so will try friend for that. The other problem I seem to have as I mentioned is I hide the form1 and not close it not to have it lose any information such as swedgeLC. But when in form1 if I open for example form3 then form 2 and form 3 appear and not just for form3. I dont see why. For each Radio button clicked it says: Frm2.Show()        Me.Hide(), and same for frm3 if that radio button is clicked frm3.show() me.hide

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. I figured out the problem, why other forms would open it was set to checkchanged and not (Private Sub OptExtra_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OptExtra.Click) for the private sub. Now my data is coming over.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).